# Aim at moving target (or predicting target's position at time it takes for projectile to hit it)

Tags: math, vector, 3d, game-engine, prediction

I have a game where I know the location and velocity of my target.  I know my own location and the speed of my projectile.  I want to determine either

- the location of the intersection between my projectile fired and the target, or
- the time taken for my projectile to intersect the target

All entities are travelling with constant speed and direction which makes life easier.  I have been trying to work out the maths for some time but cannot quite get it right.  I know that the predicted location of the target intersecting the projectile will be

Pp = Tp + Tv * t

Where Pp is the predicted position, Tp is the current target position, Tv is the target velocity, and t is time.

I also know that  t = |Pp - Sp| / Bs

where Sp is my (source) position and Fs is the projectile (bullet) speed.  But I cannot figure out a way to solve this to get either Pp or t.

Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks

*I found a website detailing one method but this doesnt seem to work (http://howlingmoonsoftware.com/wordpress/leading-a-target/).  My verification method to determine if it worked was to use the predicted position to determine the time for the target to reach it, and for the projectile to reach it.  These should be very similar but in my game they are out by almost a factor of 2.*

Comment: Do you know with certainty that your projectile _will_ hit the target? What if the target is twice as fast as your bullet? What if the target is moving north, and your bullet is moving south?

Comment: This is a solved problem: ballistics.  People have been doing this since WWII.  It's an iterative physics problem, so it's not trivial or a closed form thing.

Comment: @duffymo, I agree that there's no closed form solution for real-world ballistic problems, but I think there is a solution if there is no gravity or air resistance, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: Fair enough - two simultaneous equations, one for target and the othe for projectile.  Either there's a hit (both at the same point in space and time w/in some tolerance) or a miss.

Comment: It's a bit more interesting if the speed of the bullet is constant, but you're free to change the direction that you fire it in. In that case, if you treat time as a third spatial dimension, the problem is equivalent to finding the intersection of a ray (the target) and a cone (the bullet)

Comment: I know that all speeds are constant. I am free to aim in any direction and I know that the projectile is faster than the target therefore a hit is guaranteed.  I don't think it will require iteration. I'm pretty sure there will be a definite solution but just not sure what that would be!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using the cosine rule and quadratic equation at the same time as finding another solution online.

based on the cosine rule

c^2 = a^2 + b^2 -2ab.cos(C)

We know the angle C as it is the angle between the targets direction, and our relative location from the target

We know b as it is the distance between us and the target

We know a is time * target speed

We know c is time * projectile speed

this reduces down to get the quadratic

(projspeed^2 - targetvelocity^2)*t^2 + 2*targetvelocity*distancefromtarget*cos(C)*t - distancefromtarget^2 = 0

this can be solved using quadratic alternate form:

t = 2c / (-b + sqrt(b^2 -4ac))

Once we have t we can use PredictionPos = TargetPos + t * TargetVelocity

To verify the result is correct we can work out the time for the target to reach the destination and the projectile to reach the destination - these should be equal

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the quadratic equation is actually t = (-b ± sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) / 2a.
I would have added this as a comment, but I lack the required reputation.